# comment out line between in a file based on pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, postgresql

File: /home/jian/Desktop/pg_sources/main/postgres/src/test/regress/sql/test_setup.sql

```
246: --
247: -- Create some C functions that will be used by various tests.
248: --
249: 
250: CREATE FUNCTION binary_coercible(oid, oid)
251:     RETURNS bool
252:     AS :'regresslib', 'binary_coercible'
253:     LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
254: 
255: CREATE FUNCTION ttdummy ()
256:     RETURNS trigger
257:     AS :'regresslib'
258:     LANGUAGE C;
259: 
260: CREATE FUNCTION get_columns_length(oid[])
261:     RETURNS int
262:     AS :'regresslib'
263:     LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

I don't think these content will ever be changed.

current I am using

```
sed -i '250,263 s/^/--/' /home/jian/Desktop/pg_sources/main/postgres/src/test/regress/sql/test_setup.sql
```

to comment out thess function, but it's not safe, new line can add before easily.
So I am try to find a way to comment out these lines.

pattern would be:
comment out line begin with have pattern "C functions"
loop through line by line, end with last  line have pattern "LANGUAGE C"

Comment: There is only one line with `C functions`, but there are several with `LANGUAGE C`. Your pattern will only comment out the first `CREATE`. Please edit the question to show exactly what the output should be. Did you mean the **last** `LANGUAGE C` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    /C functions/ { beg=NR }
    /LANGUAGE C/  { end=NR }
    beg { a[NR]=$0; next }
    { print }
    END {
        for ( i=beg; i<=NR; i++ ) {
            print ( (i>end) || (a[i] ~ /^--/) ? "" : "--" ) a[i]
        }
    }
' test_setup.sql
--
-- Create some C functions that will be used by various tests.
--
--
--CREATE FUNCTION binary_coercible(oid, oid)
--    RETURNS bool
--    AS :'regresslib', 'binary_coercible'
--    LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
--
--CREATE FUNCTION ttdummy ()
--    RETURNS trigger
--    AS :'regresslib'
--    LANGUAGE C;
--
--CREATE FUNCTION get_columns_length(oid[])
--    RETURNS int
--    AS :'regresslib'
--    LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Comment: it will in stdout. how can I make effect in the file. later I need git checkout to undo it.

Comment: Same as any other Unix tool, change `test_setup.sql` to `test_setup.sql > tmp && mv tmp test_setup.sql`. Or if you're using GNU awk use `-i inplace` (see the man page).

Answer (score 1):

Finding the last end marker usually can be achieved by reversing the input and then searching the range as `/end-match/,/start-match/`. That way all other `end-match` patterns inbetween are included.

e.g.

```
 tac test_setup.sql | 
    sed '/LANGUAGE C/,/C function/s/^/--/;s/^----/--/' | 
    tac
```

or with `awk`

```
tac test_setup.sql | 
   awk '/LANGUAGE C/,/C function/{ if ($0!~/^--/) {sub(/^/,"--",$0)}}1' | 
   tac
```

or much simpler as suggested by @EdMorton:

```
tac test_setup.sql | 
   awk '/LANGUAGE C/,/C function/{sub(/^(--)?/,"--")}1' |
   tac
```

Comment: regarding the awk script - `$0!~/^--/` can be written as just `!/^--/` but the whole of `if ($0!~/^--/) {sub(/^/,"--",$0)` can be written as just `sub(/^(--)?/,"--")`, no need for an `if` test first and no need for `$0` as the 3rd arg to sub() as that's the default.

Comment: @EdMorton One cannot use `!/^--/` here, as combining the pattern match with the range is not allowed and there is no workaround. See [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) last three paragraphs. Agreed on the second part, though. Very elegant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "cannot use...", maybe I wasn't clear - I'm saying that anywhere you write `$0!~/^--/` it can be written as just `!/^--/` instead so you could replace `if ($0!~/^--/)` with `if (!/^--/)` in your original script.

Comment: @EdMorton My bad. I though you meant the following kind of combination `/start/,/end/ && !/string/ {command}`

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. FWIW I'd never use a range expression for those kind of "any change requires a rewrite or duplicate code" reasons, see [is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk). So instead of your current code I'd use a flag, e.g. `awk '/LANGUAGE C/{f=1} f{sub(/^(--)?/,"--"); if (/C function/) f=0} 1'` so if I need to make any changes in future it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'if /^CREATE \s FUNCTION /fff/^ \s+ LANGUAGE/ { put "-- " ~ $_ } else { put $_ };'  file
```

This Raku answer comments out each `CREATE FUNCTION` paragraph individually. It uses Raku's `/…/fff/…/` "flip-flop" operator.

Sample Input:

```
CREATE FUNCTION binary_coercible(oid, oid)
    RETURNS bool
    AS :'regresslib', 'binary_coercible'
    LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;

CREATE FUNCTION ttdummy ()
    RETURNS trigger
    AS :'regresslib'
    LANGUAGE C;

CREATE FUNCTION get_columns_length(oid[])
    RETURNS int
    AS :'regresslib'
    LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Sample Output:

```
-- CREATE FUNCTION binary_coercible(oid, oid)
--     RETURNS bool
--     AS :'regresslib', 'binary_coercible'
--     LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;

-- CREATE FUNCTION ttdummy ()
--     RETURNS trigger
--     AS :'regresslib'
--     LANGUAGE C;

-- CREATE FUNCTION get_columns_length(oid[])
--     RETURNS int
--     AS :'regresslib'
--     LANGUAGE C STRICT STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/fff
https://docs.raku.org/language/5to6-nutshell#if_elsif_else_unless
https://raku.org